# Algorithm for fastest division below threshold

Tags: algorithms

Take a number `i`. You need to split it in two pieces as many times as necessary so that all splits are less than or equal to `j`. How does one obtain this with the minimum number of splits? Examples:

Splitting it in half is optimal here:

```
i = 4, j = 2
4 -> 2, 2 // (1 split)
```

However, splitting in half is not optimal here:

```
i = 9, j = 3
9 -> 5, 4 // Split nine in half
5 -> 3, 2 // Then you have to split the 5
4 -> 2, 2 // and the 4 (3 splits)
```

The optimal solution here would be:

```
i = 9, j = 3
9 -> 6, 3
6 -> 3, 3 // (2 splits)
```

Is there some straightforward way to obtain the optimal split without brute-force iteration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The optimal strategy is the greedy one: repeatedly split chunks of size $j$. This strategy results in $\lceil \frac{i}{j} \rceil - 1$ splits. We can prove that this strategy is optimal by induction on $i$. The strategy is clearly optimal for $i \leq j$. Now suppose that we split $i > j$ as $i = i_1 + i_2$. In total, this choice will use up at least this many splits:
$$
1 + \lceil \tfrac{i_1}{j} \rceil - 1 + \lceil \tfrac{i_2}{j} \rceil - 1 = \lceil \tfrac{i_1}{j} \rceil + \lceil \tfrac{i_2}{j} \rceil - 1.
$$
Let $\alpha = i/j$, $\alpha_1 = i_1/j$, $\alpha_2 = i_2/j$, so that $\alpha = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$. To complete the proof, notice that $\lceil \alpha_1 \rceil + \lceil \alpha_2 \rceil \geq \lceil \alpha \rceil$, and so the quantity above is always at least $\lceil \tfrac{i}{j} \rceil - 1$, as claimed.

I have described one optimal strategy. Using the proof above, we can actually describe *all* optimal strategies. Splitting $i$ to $i_1+i_2$ is optimal iff $\lceil \frac{i_1}{j} \rceil + \lceil \frac{i_2}{j} \rceil = \lceil \frac{i}{j} \rceil$. When does that happen? Define
$$
i = aj-b, \quad i_1 = a_1j-b_1, \quad i_2 = a_2j-b_2,
$$
where $0 \leq b,b_1,b_2 < j$. A splitting is optimal iff $a_1 + a_2 = a$. Notice that
$$
i_2 + i_2 = (a_1+a_2)j - b_1 - b_2.
$$
This shows that the splitting is optimal iff $b_1 + b_2 = b$ (rather than $b + j$).

Answer (score 4):

For a given $i,j$ you want the end result to be $\lceil i/j\rceil$ pieces of size $j$ and at most one piece of size $<j$. No matter how you decide to do the splits, this separation will require at least $\lceil i/j\rceil-1$ splits. The simplest way to do this is to split $i$ into pieces of size $j$ and $i-j$. Then split the $i-j$ piece into pieces of size $j$ and $i-2j$. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: One way to see the intuition for why this works : Each split only adds one more piece. So you need to do exactly as many splits as the number of pieces you need to add. Splitting of pieces of exactly the right size (j) has a 1:1 correspondence between the splits and the newly created pieces.

Comment: @sgauria that made it a bit clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, the optimal strategy is to repeatedly chop pieces of size $j$ off the number, until what's left is no greater than $j$.  This will require $\lceil i/j \rceil - 1$ splits, and yield $\lceil i/j \rceil$ pieces.

An easy way to see that this method is optimal it to first note that, since each split turns one piece into two, and so increases the total number of pieces by one, the final number of pieces you're left with is always one plus the number of splits.

Next, observe that, if you have $k$ pieces of size at most $j$, their total size is obviously at most $jk$.  Thus, if $k < i/j$, then $jk < i$, and so $k < i/j$ pieces of size at most $j$ cannot possibly sum to $i$.  Therefore, the smallest number of pieces that can sum to $i$ must be at least $i/j$, and the optimal number of splits must thus be at least $i/j - 1$.

Obviously, you cannot make just part of a split, so the number of splits must be an integer.  The smallest integer greater than or equal to $i/j - 1$ is, [by definition](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), $\lceil i/j - 1 \rceil = \lceil i/j \rceil - 1$.